# Eigenvalues norm of matrix sum

Tags: matrices

For the sum of matrices $A+B$, is it possible to calculate its spectral radius or some inequality related to its eigenvalues by some norm inequality? If the answer is yes, I cannot see how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just assume T=A+B and apply the theory of linear operates on it.

Comment: Theory of linear operates?

Comment: You might read about Weyl's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality

Comment: The Grönwall's Inequality is also useful.